# to pass parameter to web api through ajax call

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have below ajax query which returns me json from controller

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(
      "api/OutletPOC/GetHomeTab?bizId=1",
      function (data) {
          $("#homeTabDesc").append(data.HomeDesc);
          $(".test").hide();
          $("#hometabcontent").show();
      });
});
```

the controller action is as below

```
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("GetHomeTab")]
    public HomeTabModel GetHomeTab(int bizId)
    {
        var outlet = db.Info.Where(t => t.BizId == bizId).SingleOrDefault();
        return new HomeTabModel 
        { 
            HomeDesc = outlet.BizHomeDesc, 
            HomeTabText = outlet.BizHomeTabText 
        };
    }
```

Now my question is: curently i am sending hard coded value of bizId to web api. I want to send this value dynamically. How can i achieve this? I have that value in my route config file. The code is as below-

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{bizId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", bizId = 1 }
        );
    }
```

I am new to this. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

no, actually after much research, i came up with this solution and this works fine for me....

In controller,

```
public ActionResult Index(int bizId)
    {
        ViewBag.BizId = bizId;
        return View();
    }
```

and in View,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(
      "api/OutletPOC/GetHomeTab?bizId=@ViewBag.BizId",
      function (data) {
          $("#homeTabDesc").append(data.HomeDesc);
          $(".test").hide();
          $("#hometabcontent").show();
      });
});
```

Comment: Just an FYI, your solution uses a completely different framework (ASP.NET MVC) from the one you are using in your question (ASP.NET Web API)

Comment: nope, m using mvc4 framework. its the smae one for question as well as answer

Comment: In your original question you are returning HomeTabModel which you can't do in MVC.  You state Web API in your question.  In you answer you use ActionResult which does not exist in Web API.

Comment: The index action is written in other controller. This Index action calls view which calls the apicontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a data object as part of the GetJson call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(
      "api/OutletPOC/GetHomeTab",{bizId : 1},
      function (data) {
          $("#homeTabDesc").append(data.HomeDesc);
          $(".test").hide();
          $("#hometabcontent").show();
      });
});
```

Taking this one step further you could wrap this in a function.

```
function makeCall(id)
{

     $.getJSON("api/OutletPOC/GetHomeTab",{bizId : id},
              function (data) {
                  $("#homeTabDesc").append(data.HomeDesc);
                  $(".test").hide();
                  $("#hometabcontent").show();
              });

}
```

Also look into using promises.

$.getJSON().then().done();

Comment: no, actually after much research, i came up with this solution and this works fine for me....

Comment: What solution did you use in the end, if you meant the solution I proposed can you mark it as the answer need the points :-)

Comment: I cannot mark my answer as answer in 20 hours..so can you please mark it.